# 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I'm getting this error:

> 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint
>   fails.

I've located them and try to get rid of the references with

```
alter table tillhör drop foreign key kat_id;
```

But getting this error instead:

> #1025 - Error on rename of '.\recept\tillh@1ir' to
>   '.\recept#sql2-1570-3cb' (errno: 152).

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Before you query run

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0
```

then set it to 1 after you`re done.

Comment: Does it take away all foreign key in the database or in one table. Still not so familiar with SQL. The problem is I can't insert anything in the first table because of the foreign key.

Comment: No it just ignores foreign keys constraints until you enable it again.

Comment: But if you are not sure post the insert query and the table schema.Just write in sql SHOW CREATE TABLE yourTable and post the result.

Comment: Oh, I guess I made a mistake when I created recept. There shouldn't be a foreign key: 
CREATE TABLE `recept` (
 `rec_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `namn` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
 `portioner` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
 `beskrivning` varchar(3000) DEFAULT NULL,
 `tillagningstid` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 `svårighetsgrad` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`rec_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `recept_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`rec_id`) REFERENCES `tillhör` (`rec_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

How do I get rid of that. Tried but it want work.

Comment: ALTER TABLE recept
DROP FOREIGN KEY recept_ibfk_1

Comment: YES, YES, YES, Thank you Mihai for your help! What does the _ibfk_1 stand for?

Comment: I don't really know i guess Mysql gives foreign keys ,if you don't name them,some generic name from table name +innodb foreign key(ibfk)+number of the key.

Comment: foreign_key_checks are there for a reason. If you can't add the foreign key because it violates the constraint, you should correct the data first. Turning off checks then adding the key leaves you in an inconsistent state. Foreign key checks add overhead, if you do not want to use them, then use myisam instead.

Answer (score 15):

I face same problem. I solve this issue by clearing, i.e. deleting all data from child table and successfully done.

This is occur if child table contain some data with the foreign key that that are not in parent table i.e, if there are two table called **Person** (with column id, name, address) and **order**(with column id, person_id, order_name); **order.person_id is foreign key of person.id and order table contain person_id that is not present in person table**.

You can solve this using the following query

```
Delete from order where person_id NOT IN (select id from person where person.id = order.person_id)
```

Answer (score 7):

When I had this problem, it was due to the fact that I forgot to specify NULLS allowed when creating the foreign key id fields. I changed it after the fact, but 0's were already in the value. It could not find 0 in the matching table, and then gave this error. The fix: update the zero values to nulls.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set nulls to your from the parent to child tables 
Or set the same values eg
Child table first nam=Derick
Parent table name=Derick